# why asyncRefresh event is firing at the time of page loading

Tags: asp.net

I developing a web application in asp.net ,in that application i am using a chart control for continuous updation of data fro database ,Here i am using one event of that chart control i.e NChartcontrol_AsyncRefresh event.Actually i want to  fire this event after a button click.But at the time of page loading the AsyncRefresh event is firing before firing the button click event. Please help me

Thanks&Regards
LIJO THOMAS

Comment: Lijo njan vendum vote cheythu

Answer (score 1):

That should not happen unless the code is somehow called inside PageLoad().
Can you post some code? Also try wrapping your code inside

```
if(Page.IsPostBack)
{
   //Your code
}
```

block & see if it works.